# sql select actors play two more distinct role in the same movie

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

the question is to select actors that played 2 or more distinct roles in the same movie. 
And I got 3 table, actor (id,name) movie (id,name) and casts(aid,mid，role) (aid is the actor id and mid is the movie id)
I wrote a query like this

```
 select a.name
 from actor a, movie m, casts c
 where a.id = c.aid and m.id = casts.mid
 group by (m.name)
 having count(distinct role) > 2;
```

this didnt print the right result and I didnt see the problem with it. 
Thanks for the help!

Comment: I group the movie so that i can select actors who have 2 distinct roles or more from those groups. Is there anything wrong with my logic?

Comment: On what table is the `role` field?

Comment: Sorry it is in the cast

Comment: This question seems to contain your answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16327954/sql-using-group-by-and-having-clause

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this? Was there any error trying to execute your query?

```
select actor.name from actor, casts, movie 
 where casts.aid =actor.id 
   and casts.mid = movie.id
 group by movie.name, actor.name 
having count(distinct role) >= 2
```

Answer (score 1):

As the `casts` table appears to contain one row per actor, movie, and role (unless you are leaving out other columns), any time a single pair of unique values of `aid` and `mid` appears on more than one row, it means the actor played more than one role in that movie. Thus, there is no reason to use `distinct`. Also because your desired result doesn't contain the movie names, your query doesn't need and shouldn't use the `movie` table.

If it is true that the `cast` table has only one row for each unique combination of (`aid`, `mid`, and `role`) then the following should work:

```
select name
  from actor
 where id in (  select aid
                  from casts
              group by aid, mid
                having count(*) > 1)
```