# TSQL - How can I find rows where the name is like an expression and another field has a count greater than 1?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, count, where-clause

I need to find instances where a customer has a particular name and has bought more than 1 of the same item.

I thought it would be something like below, but I get an error stating that an aggregate may not appear in the where clause.

I also tried `HAVING` but I'm not sure about the syntax.

```
SELECT 
    cust.FirstName, cust.LastName, prod.ProductNumber, prod.Name
FROM 
    Ours.Customer as cust
INNER JOIN 
    Ours.SalesOrderMaster as som ON cust.CustomerID = som.CustomerID
INNER JOIN 
    Ours.SalesOrderDetail as sod ON som.SalesOrderID = sod.SalesOrderID
INNER JOIN 
    Ours.Product as prod ON sod.ProductID = prod.ProductID
WHERE 
    cust.FirstName LIKE 'Joe' AND Count(prod.ProductID) > 1;
```

Comment: You have to use the HAVING clause. It is basically a where clause for aggregates.

Comment: Take a peek at the link below. Gives a little explanation of how to write it.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16327954/sql-using-group-by-and-having-clause

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would use a `group by` clause to group the data and then filter the groups using a `having` clause.

Unless I misunderstood your question I think this might be what you want:

```
SELECT cust.FirstName, cust.LastName, prod.ProductNumber, prod.Name
FROM Ours.Customer as cust
INNER JOIN Ours.SalesOrderMaster as som ON cust.CustomerID = som.CustomerID
INNER JOIN Ours.SalesOrderDetail as sod ON som.SalesOrderID = sod.SalesOrderID
INNER JOIN Ours.Product as prod ON sod.ProductID = prod.ProductID
WHERE cust.FirstName LIKE 'Joe' 
GROUP BY cust.FirstName, cust.LastName, prod.ProductNumber, prod.Name
HAVING Count(prod.ProductID) > 1;
```

This would first apply the where clause to filter out all rows with FirstName like Joe, and then group the rows by name and productnumber and filter out those groups with count > 1.

Comment: I tried this and it returns zero rows but is closer. I know that there are customers that have bought the exact same productID more than once. When I query the table for just one customer and ORDER BY the productID I can find them. I appreciate your help but I'm still missing something.

Comment: @RyanPicou Without seeing your actual table structure and some sample data it's hard to guide you further. This query should do what you ask for though. Take a look at this SQL Fiddle for an example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/c7a26/1 Maybe there's something different in your setup that I didn't get right in the fiddle?

Comment: Thanks, the fiddle make it clear for me after I added more details. Your answer is correct, the results didn't exist in my data. I thought they did but I was misreading my own table *face palm*